# Subir foto, que quede vertical y con la fecha

Tags: php, mysql

al subir una imagen se sube de forma horizontal y necesito que quede vertical, además que contenga la fecha y se visualicé una vez subida la imagen.
He buscado muchos códigos pero no se como implementarlos en el código. Espero que me puedan ayudar.
Gracias!!!.

```
<?php
    require_once("../DBConn.php");
    $status = "";

$id_sucursal=$_GET['id_suc'];
$nombre_suc=$_GET['nombre_suc'];

if ($_POST["action"] == "upload") {
    // obtenemos los datos del archivo
    $tamano = $_FILES["archivo"]['size'];
    $tipo = $_FILES["archivo"]['type'];
    $archivo = $_FILES["archivo"]['name'];
    
    //$prefijo = substr(md5(uniqid(rand())),0,6);

    if ($archivo != "") {
        // guardamos el archivo a la carpeta files
        $destino =  "files/".$archivo;
        if (copy($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],$destino)) {
            $status = "Archivo subido: <b>".$archivo."</b>";
        } else {
            $status = "Error al subir el archivo";
        }
    } else {
        $status = "Error al subir archivo";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ten cuidado con la forma como revisas los archivos. Es posible que el visor que usas esté rotando las imagenes, o que las imágenes en realidad sí tengan las dimensiones que se ven al subirlas, y dentro de la metadata tengan marcado que "están rotadas" (orientation flag en la metadata EXIF de un archivo JPEG, por ejemplo). La fecha... igual, hay fecha en la metadata y hay fecha puesta por el OS al archivo. Depende!

Comment: Antes de subir las imagenes estan verticales y cuando ya estan subidas salen horizontales, y respecto a las fechas quiero que el usuario pueda dejar la fecha en la cual la subio y al revisar la imagen que se vea.